# Windows Services - Common Ports to Open in Firewall

Tags: windows, security, firewall, port, windows-service

I've always had trouble finding firewall port information for some windows-based software/services. For example,http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832017 gives me the ports but there's no differentiation between INTERNAL (e.g. LAN) and the ones that are EXTERNAL (to the internet). The firewall config from Desktop to AD Server will undoubtedly be different than from AD Server to AD Server and of course from AD DNS Server to the Internet.

I want to lock down the interfaces between my desktop computers and my servers and then also between servers as well (AD to AD, etc.).

I have a hardware firewall in between the desktops and servers, and the server switch has firewall embedded as well. **I want to start with NO ports allowed and then only open up what is necessary to run the services on each server.** I have a lot of SQL Server, AD, DNS, Exchange, Terminal Services, etc. servers and each one has a slightly different port configuration depending on whether or not it is talking to the internet (Exchange, DNS) or the local servers (Active Directory replication, CIFS shares) or desktops (SQL Server, Terminal ServiceS).

To make it a little more general (and useful to other people), I was hoping we could get a list of all the common Windows apps/services and the ports needed to the internet/dmz (in/out), to "trusted" LAN (server to server) (in/out), and then untrusted LAN (server to desktop).

Let me start off with a couple, please add them to the list. Also, please include whether or not this is a "default" service within Windows (e.g. Exchange isn't, but SMB would be).

Some I pulled from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832017
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124075(EXCHG.65).aspx

```
Remote Desktop - default if enabled
DMZ - None (usually)
T LAN - 3389 (TCP IN/OUT)
U LAN - None (or selected desktops; IT support etc.)

NT - NetBIOS - default if enabled
DMZ - None
T/U LAN - 137, 138 (UDP I/O), 139 (TCP I/O)

SMB - default
DMZ - None
T/U LAN - 445 (TCP I/O) ?

DNS - only if installed within AD
DMZ - 53 (TCP/UDP O) 
T/U LAN - 53 (TCP/UDP I/O)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't totally clear but I'll do my best...

One thing to remember is that any program can use any port it likes.  That's how spyware and malware manage to thrive in some environments... by using common, well known ports and pretend to be something else.

A less malicious example would be the Skype program which will try to find a port to use but will ultimately use ports 80 (HTTP/web port) and 443 (SSL port) if it has to.

With that in mind... you should do a scan of the PC(s) in question using a program like nmap or nessus, etc... (there's A LOT of them out there) to find out what ports are open and then decide how you want to set up your firewall.

Here is a link to common port assignments to give you a starting point for what MIGHT be running on that port:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959833.aspx

For example, port 53 is commonly used for DNS.  If you don't have any need for DNS or you don't have a DNS server running on that machine, you can block it.

Along that same line, you should make sure your server isn't running services it doesn't need to.  If you see port 53 open on your server and you have a DNS server (you're not using) running turn it OFF. ;-)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with KPWINC on the ports, anything can use any port. If your goal is protecting your servers, I would place a hardware firewall in between your users and servers and make sure it has proxies that it can run on the ports that do have to be open. That way if the traffic comes out on port 80, the firewall can see if it is HTTP traffic and drop it if it is not. We use a Watchguard X1000 to do the job for us, but I know there are others out there.

And yes I can already hear some people saying "But viruses may make their traffic look like HTTP". True, but then your server has to be vuneralble as well with the HTTP service.

Comment: I have a hardware firewall -- I want to start with NO ports allowed and then only open up what is running on each server. Question amended.

Comment: I agree with the way you are setting things up. Block everything, ingress and egress, then only allow what you HAVE to have. Does your hardware firewall report what port traffic it is blocking? If so I would go from there and run the port number. This website (done by Steve Gibson and grc.com) http://www.grc.com/port_80.htm is fantastic for learning what a port typically does. Change the number in the domain, or use the box on the page to do so.